# Why my Java while loop iterates half times

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

```
//some code here
    String x;
    while ((x = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(inputStream.readLine());
    }
    inputStream.close();
}
```

Hello I am beginner at Java and My while loop should give an output like
aaasd1
aaasd2
aaasd3
aaasd4
aaasd5
aaasd6
But it gives
aaasd2
aaasd4
aaasd6

When i change the println to `System.out.println(x);` it gives output like it should do. Do anyone know what is the problem. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `inputStream.readLine()` you read one line and advance the file pointer to the next line and since you do it twice, once in the `while loop` header and once when printing then only every second line is printed. Print x instead

```
String x;
while ((x = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(x);
}
inputStream.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you call `readLine()` twice but only print every second value. That is, the value assigned to `x` in your `while` expression is not printed. When you use `System.out.println(x);`, you print every value.

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code:

```
x = inputStream.readLine()
```

Reads the next line and stores it in `x`.  But then you never use `x`.  Instead, you do this:

```
System.out.println(inputStream.readLine());
```

That reads the next line *after* the one stored in `x` and prints it out.  Replace that with:

```
System.out.println(x);
```

That will print out the line you just read in the loop condition.